# Downloading Dreamspark MS Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: wget

i have been trying to download windows xp, from the dreamspark website.
unfortunately a secure download manager(SDM) is used to download the iso image.
SDM will only run on windows. how do i remedy this situation.

Answer (score 5):

For downloading the SDM File you can use the Python script: https://github.com/RadekSimkanic/Linux-SDM-Downloader.

Answer (score 1):

If SDM is an application then you can install  it with WINE.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

then type as

```
wine /path/to/yourSDM.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Internet Explorer 6 in wine trough winetricks, becaus de SDM is really a kind of simplified Internet Explorer window.

```
winetricks ie6
```

Anyway, I had the same problem as you, and ended up downloading it from a Windows machine. Is not an Ubuntu problem really, is a "feature" built in by Microsoft.

Check this for further details:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28884

By the way, be sure the SDM you download is the SDM.msi version! If you try to download it from Ubuntu, it will detect you're not running Linux and the website will default to the SDM.pkg (which is the Mac OSX version).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have – despite several tries – always failed to run the SDM in Wine.

So far, the only option I've found to be working is using a Virtual Machine running Windows to run the SDM. Which of course leaves you with having to have a running Windows in order to download Windows.

If you have no Windows available (at all, no matter which version), your best bet is getting someone with a Windows machine to download the ISO for you.